# Getting the first strong tag in a class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to go through a list of 100 items and only get the first strong tag from the class in each list item(some have 1 and others have more than 1).

In the code that I have tried, it gets all the items with strong tags so instead of a total of 100 items, it gets 128 items.

**This is the code i have:**

```
for i in range(100):
    artist = soup.find_all("strong" , {"class" : "chartItem-artist-artistName"})[i].getText()
    print(artist)
```

**Here is the HTML code being webscraped:** [Screenshot of the HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8hgd.png)

- The class I am targeting is highlighted in red (chartItem-artist-artistInfo)
- The item I am trying to pull is highlighted in blue (only the first strong tag)

I only want to get 'DaBaby' and not '&' or 'Stunna 4 Vegas'

Comment: Have you tried `find` instead of `find_all`? As in `soup.find("strong" , {"class" : "chartItem-artist-artistName"})`

Comment: @kuco23 I did but it only returns 1/100 items (first item from the entire list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace:

```
for i in range(100):
    artist = soup.find_all("strong" , {"class" : "chartItem-artist-artistName"})[i].getText()
    print(artist)
```

with:

```
artists = soup.select('div.chartItem-artist-info strong:nth-child(1)')
for artist in artists:
    print(artist.get_text())
```

Comment: I get this error when I try the code above (from print statement): Traceback (most recent call last):

    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Can you post the HTML in text form?

Comment: @Kareem no when i look at it wit a computer i can see where i got it wrong. I have updated the code... :)

Answer (score 0):

This will get text from first `<strong>` element under `class="chartItem-artist-info"`:

```
for t in soup.select('.chartItem-artist-info'):
    artist = t.strong.get_text()
    print(artist)
```